# apply sed command only if no dot before

Tags: sed

My sed command does not work as expected.

`sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/[^\.](\[[0-9]]) \n\n/\1 /g'`

I want this :

```
blabla[3]

foofoo

barbar.[4]

blabla
```

To become :

```
blabla[3] foofoo

barbar.[4]

blabla
```

That is, I just want the new lines to be deleted when there is no dot before "[".

But my sed command does not take into account my `[^\.]`.

Without `[^\.]`, I get :

```
blabla[3] foofoo

barbar.[4] blabla
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `sed` (should work with non-gnu sed also):

```bash
sed -E -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 's/((^|[^.])\[[0-9]+]) *\n\n/\1 /g' file
blabla[3] foofoo

barbar.[4]

blabla
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/mJkhgd)

Note that we are matching `(^|[^.])` to allow `[<digits>]` to appear at the line start as well. It is also important to keep this part in capture group so that we don't miss out on this char in replacement.

Comment: It does not work.  The command works because there's a space after "blabla[3]". If you remove the space, it no longer works.  I've removed the space in the question. "(\[[0-9]+])" has no effect.

Comment: @trogne remove the space in the regex ..

Comment: I did that. But still, "(^|[^.])" has no effect at all : The lines after ".[4]" gets also deleted.

Comment: @trogne I tested this `sed -E -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 's/((^|[^.])\[[0-9]+])\n\n/\1 /g' test.txt` and came up correct.  (without space)

Comment: Ok, it's because of my environment. In git bash, it works. But in windows cmd, `[^.]` does not work : `"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sed" -E -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 's/((^|[^.])\[[0-9]+])\n\n/\1 /g'`.    I wonder if there's a trick to make `[^.]` work in cmd...

Comment: Ahh I think it goes without saying that the assumption was that you were in a true bash environment.

Comment: I have made trailing space optional by using `*` to make it match 0 or more spaces before matching 2 line breaks.

Comment: A `gnu sed` should work same on Windows CMD as well, however I don't have access to Windows to test it.